# Searching each property value of an IQueryable collection of T against the value of a search query. How do I test for NOT NULL and CONTAINS together?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, expression-trees, iqueryable

I am trying search each property value of an IQueryable collection of T against the value of a search query.  I have the following function and would like to know how do I ALSO test for NOT NULL and CONTAINS together?

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> PropertySearch
{
  get
  {
     // Object that is passed to the lambda expression
     ParameterExpression instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "val");
     Expression whereExpr = Expression.Constant(true); // default is val => True

     var _properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
     foreach (var prop in _properties)
     {
        var query = _httpRequest["query"].ToLower();
        var property = Expression.Property(instance, prop);
        var toStringCall = Expression.Call(Expression.Call(
            property,
            "ToString", 
            new Type[0]), 
            typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", new Type[0]));
        whereExpr = Expression.And(whereExpr, 
            Expression.Call(toStringCall, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), 
            Expression.Constant(query)));
     }
     return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(whereExpr, instance);
}}
```

Comment: The easiest option is to just hard code an example lambda and then look at it using the debugger to see what the exact sub-expressions are.  In this case, you simply need to call `Expression.Equals`.  You're already most of the way there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a search extensions nuget package that performs this type of check.  For your example I would do something like the following.

*Note, this is without an IDE so may have some errors*

```
/* *** Start: These can be made private reaonly fields ***/
var comparisonExpr = Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
var zeroExpression = Expression.Constant(0)
var nullExpression = Expression.Constant(null)
MethodInfo IndexOfMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("IndexOf", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) });  
/* *** End ***/

Expression finalExpression = null
ParameterExpression instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "val");
var _properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
var query = _httpRequest["query"].ToLower();
var queryExpr = Expression.Constant(query);

foreach (var prop in _properties)
{
    //Get property
    var propertyExpr = Expression.Property(instance, prop);
    //Get property as string
    var propStringExpr = Expression.Call(property, "ToString", new Type[0]);
    //Perform IndexOf call
    var indexOfExpr = Expression.Call(propStringExpr, 
                                       IndexOfMethod, 
                                       queryExpr, 
                                       comparisonExpr);

    // Check index of is greater than or equal to zero
    var containsExpr = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(containsExpr, zeroExpression);

    if(finalExpression == null)
    {
        finalExpression = containsExp;
    }
    else
    {
        finalExpression = Expression.AndAlso(containsExpr);
    }
}

return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(finalExpression, instance);
```

I've removed the need for `ToLower()` and instead used `IndexOf` with a string comparison type

If you want to see how I have achieved similar functionality, take a look at [NinjaNye.SearchExtensions](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NinjaNye.SearchExtensions) on Github

### https://github.com/ninjanye/SearchExtensions

If you wanted to search a collection of `IQueryable` you could use [NinjaNye.SearchExtensions](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NinjaNye.SearchExtensions) as follows

```
string query = _httpRequest["query"];
var result = data.SearchAll().Containing(query);
```

This will search all **string properties** (not all properties as you have above) and return just those where **any property** mathes the search term.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) so you don't have to mess with expression trees yourself.